# Advantages of naming operations in Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

For operations in Tensorflow, we have the option to pick a `name`.

Example:

`tf.argmin(input, dimension, name=None)`

What does this do? Does it help with debugging? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a `name` for ops and vars helps you to build a logically correct graph.
You can visualize, then, you graph in Tensorboard and see if everything you defined is exactly as you thought.

In general, giving a name to a variable or an op is a good practice. Further, when you export a graph and you re-use it somewhere, it's unhandy to use the default generated names by tensorflow to interact with the graph. You'll surely prefer to work with name with a sense.
Think about something like `BatchNorm/relu:0` vs `BatchNorm/network_output:0`. The latter is more clear and describes exactly what you meant when defined that operation